# Security issue with Oracle Reports

Tags: oracle, security, oraclereports

I have a problem of security with Oracle Reports. To have a report called you have to put together the url, in the url, there is a parameter called userid. This parameter is not encrypted and can be seen from the source of the html. I have tried putting a wbsite inbetween to send those parameters in a post form, algo, I have turn the parameters in hexadecimal but reports converts it to ascii again.

Has anybody encountered this problem? I dont know what else to do.

The parameter is called "input_hidden_parameters"

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs for [Oracle Reports Services](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/bi.1111/b32121/pbr_sec_arch001.htm#CBHHGBHA) 11g:

> 15.1.3.3 Data Source Security
>
> Data source security defines the users or roles that can access the
>   data within the given data source. A report might access multiple data
>   sources and the current user must have privileges on all of the data
>   sources accessed by the report in order to run it and view the output.
>   The data source administrator (typically a DBA) grants access to data
>   sources. Data source security must be established and in place prior
>   to configuring your reports environment.
>
> You can provide for data source security in two different ways with
>   Oracle Reports Services:
>
> You can associate data source connection information with a Single
>   Sign-On user. In this case, the first time a user attempts to access
>   the data source, Oracle Delegated Administration Services prompts them
>   to create a resource for their data source connection. After the user
>   creates this data source resource, OracleAS Single Sign-On associates
>   it with the user in Oracle Internet Directory. Once the data source
>   resource is associated with the Single Sign-On user, it becomes part
>   of their Single Sign-On identity and they can access the data source
>   without having to log in to it separately. This method has two key
>   advantages. First, it enables each user to gain access to the data
>   source through their Single Sign-On identity without having to login
>   separately. Second, **it enables a single report URL to be used by many
>   users because the data source login information is stored with the
>   user's identity and therefore does not have to be hard coded into the
>   report's URL or a key mapping**.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Key Map file](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28389_01/bi.1111/b32121/pbr_run013.htm) cgicmd.dat to hide the database connection string and other parameters.